# Is there any way I can animate my background image to have a scrolling / like marquee type effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css, background, background-image

I have tried a lot of different ways using animation keyframes. I cannot seem to be able to do it.

I basically want my background animate left to right and repeat, like a marquee but as my background.

It seems like the only solution for me is to make a gif for my background, but that is really time extensive for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to avoid jumps in the animation (once it reachs the end and start again) I would move the image with `repeat-x` to an exagerated amount of x coordenates like this:

```css
html {
  margin:0;padding:0; height:100%;
}
body  {
  height:100%;
  background-image:url(https://i.imgur.com/aCDecXL.jpg);
  background-size: auto 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
  animation: scroll 700000s infinite linear;
  
}
@keyframes scroll {
  from { background-position: 0%; }
  to { background-position: 90000000%; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,,this makes a lot more sense now <3

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```css
#animate-area { 
    width: 560px; 
    height: 400px; 
    background-image: url('http://labs.designoptimizer.net/snip/bg-clouds.png');
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes animatedBackground {
    from { background-position: 0 0; }
    to { background-position: 100% 0; }
}
```

```html
<div id="animate-area"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use animation keyframe to make it work

```css
.background{
background: url(https://dummyimage.com/1500x700/);
    width: 560px; 
 height: 400px; 
background-position: 0px 0px;
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: cover;
    animation: animation_back 2s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes animation_back {
 from { background-position: 0 0; }
 to { background-position: 200% 0; }
}
```

```html
<div class="background">

</div>
```